# Blocking ports makes the domain almost 100% secure?

Tags: attacks

With one of the most reliable tools like pass the hash or online brute forcing tools like hydra requiring common ports like 445 to be open in the domain, will blocking those common ports secure the domain completely, since even most tools in metasploit require some type of port to be open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a port is not needed, keep it closed.

However, for day-to-day operation, you'll need to have a few ports open - 25 (SMTP), 80 (HTTP), and 443 (HTTPS) for example.
Via these, a payload can be delivered - viruses spreading by mail being a famous example, XSS attacks another one.

If you completely disconnect your computer from the internet, you're pretty safe nowadays, as most attacks are made via the net. But complete disconnection is rarely feasible - you wouldn't be able to browse the web, or to offer an online service (like a website).

Even if you can afford to have your computer completely disconnected, a number of attack vectors remain. Gullible users/operators come to mind.

Comment: What ports have to be open for reverse tcp payload to work, can it only be transmitted through port 445? or does the attacker machine have to open specific ports aswell to receive the reverse tcp back?

Answer (score 1):

100% secure never, because there is always the small chance a bug can be exploited in the netfilter or network stack. If you do not use 445 (or any other port for that matter), close it.